# Concatenate select field value and text field value in to one text filed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have following form fields

```
<input type="text" id="domain" name="domain">
<select id="sub" name="sub">
<option value="TEST.SITE">TEST.SITE</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="full" name="full">
```

How can I concatenate user inputs of text field and select field and insert that into the 3rd hidden 
field?

Ex: 
text field: HELLO
select field : TEST.SITE
value of full field should be : HELLO.TEST.SITE

Comment: do you want to join them using  dot "." ?

Comment: yup need to save value like, ABC.TEXT.SITE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` for the same:

```
  $(function(){
      $("#formId").on("submit", function(){ // change your formId here
      const domain = $("#domain").val();  //get domain value
      const sub = $("#sub").val();         // get sub value
      $("#full").val(domain + "." + sub); // join them with .
    })
 })
```

Comment: hi i tried that but when i tried to save the value in the db it says the filed has null value..

Comment: I have updated my code. Change your `formId` in this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, It will change the hidden field on `Blur` event of sub text field,
You can change event according to your requirement,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>

<input type="text" id="domain" name="domain">
<select id="sub" name="sub">
    <option value="TEST.SITE">TEST.SITE</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="full" name="full">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#domain').on('blur', function(){
        var domain = $('#domain').val();
        var sub = $('#sub').val();

        var full = domain + '.' + sub;
        $('#full').val( full );
    });
});
</script>
```

Working example: https://paiza.io/projects/P13ImGFxhiOfcEaEn4RxTA

Comment: value cannot be saved in the db, as it passing a null value..